# Rails: Cron jobs with whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, cron-task, whenever

I'm new to cron job as well as rails. I have installed `whenever` gem. Now I want to  delete a file from `tmp/cache/foo.txt`.

*schedule.rb*

```
every 5.minutes do
    command "rm '#{path}/tmp/cache/foo.txt' "
end
```

And when i run `whenever` command it says:

```sh
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'rm '\''/home/techbirds/shivam/tmp/cache/foo.txt'\'''

## [message] Above is your schedule file converted to cron syntax; your crontab file was not updated.
## [message] Run `whenever --help' for more options
```

So how to do it from starting?

Comment: Update your crontab with `whenever --update-crontab`

Answer (score 1):

You should update `crontab` (*configuration file that defines commands to run periodically on a desired schedule*) according to you new `schedule.rb` rules, so you should run the following command (*if this job is set to a specific environment in your `schedule.rb` you should also `--set` environment*):

```
whenever --update-crontab
```

To view your current jobs use `crontab -e` (*jobs generated by `whenever` would be enclosed in `# Begin Whenever` and `# End Whenever` blocks*).

Comment: Ok I have use that command but the file is still not deleting

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari: It is a bit vague, what exactly is not working? Do you have correct rules in the `crontab`? What is happening when you run your command from terminal?Is your path correct?

Comment: `whenever --update-crontab --set environment='staging'` This works for me , for changing env